# Creating New Comparator for TreeSet in Java

Tags: java, comparator, compareto, treeset

I have a user-defined class called User. This class implements comparable, and has the data fields ID number, followers, and following.

I want to sort the elements in the TreeSet so that the User with the most followers is first, and the User with the least followers is last. If both Users have the same number of followers, then sort based on how many people the User is following. If they are following the same number of people, then sort based on the ID number.

```
class User implements Comparable<User>
{
    private int userId;
    private ArrayList<User> following;
    private ArrayList<User> followers;
    Set<User> sortingSet = new TreeSet<User>();
}
```

I've also implemented a compareTo method

```
public int compareTo(User other)
{
    if(this.followers.size() > other.followers.size())
        return -1;

    if(this.followers.size() < other.followers.size())
        return 1;

    if(this.following.size() > other.following.size())
        return -1;

    if(this.following.size() < other.following.size())
        return 1;

    if(this.userId < other.userId)
        return -1;

    if(this.userId > other.userId)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

When I add to the TreeSet, it just sorts based on userId.

EDIT: Thanks for the help, I've made some changes to the code so far. I've removed some superfluous if statements. I've also implemented the compareTo method, but the problem still remains the same. I have also already written equals() and hashcode() methods.

EDIT2: Once again, thanks for the help everybody. I've figured out the problem, and it's related to how I initialized the followers and following ArrayLists. I'm blaming that mistake on my lack of sleep.

Comment: Each third `if` is superfluous.

Comment: I think you don't need that `Comp` or any other `Comparator` because you can implement the comparison logic in the `compareTo` method of `User`, which has to implement it because it `implements Comparable<User>`. Add proper `equals` and `hashCode` to `User` and the `TreeSet` will sort them accordingly.

Comment: Remove more if statements: `int cmpFollowers = Integer.compare(other.followers.size(), this.followers.size()); if (cmpFollowers != 0) return cmpFollowers;`

Comment: Can you post your main method where you are adding data in Set ?

Comment: It looks very strange that every `User` has such a `TreeSet`. Further, you have to understand that the properties *must not* change after the object has been added to the `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not created a comparator. You have created a thing called `Comp` which **can be compared to users**.

A compar*ator* is a thing which **compares two things**. Compar*able* is something which can **compare itself** to something.

`Comparable.compareTo` takes one argument. `Comparator.compare` takes two arguments.